# How to set up .gitignore for a fresh Magento 2 (v2.2.0) site?

Tags: installation, default, git

When I install Magento (v.2.2.0), only things set up in .git are `/pub` and `/update` directories. I obviously want to expand the theme, and add new modules to it, so why are these the only ones set up to be followed by git? Is there because of danger to compromise (change in a faulty manner some files) Magento installation, so as a secureity measure by Magento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used below file to manage project in git

```
/.buildpath
/.cache
/.metadata
/.project
/.settings
/.vscode
atlassian*
/nbproject
/robots.txt
/pub/robots.txt
/sitemap
/sitemap.xml
/pub/sitemap
/pub/sitemap.xml
/.idea
/.gitattributes
/app/config_sandbox
/app/etc/config.php
/app/etc/env.php
/app/code/Magento/TestModule*
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.actionScriptProperties
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.flexProperties
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.project
/lib/internal/flex/uploader/.settings
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.actionScriptProperties
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.flexLibProperties
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.project
/lib/internal/flex/varien/.settings
/node_modules
/.grunt
/Gruntfile.js
/package.json
/.php_cs
/.php_cs.cache
/grunt-config.json
/dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js

/pub/media/*.*
!/pub/media/.htaccess
/pub/media/attribute/*
!/pub/media/attribute/.htaccess
/pub/media/analytics/*
/pub/media/catalog/*
!/pub/media/catalog/.htaccess
/pub/media/customer/*
!/pub/media/customer/.htaccess
/pub/media/downloadable/*
!/pub/media/downloadable/.htaccess
/pub/media/favicon/*
/pub/media/import/*
!/pub/media/import/.htaccess
/pub/media/logo/*
/pub/media/theme/*
/pub/media/theme_customization/*
!/pub/media/theme_customization/.htaccess
/pub/media/wysiwyg/*
!/pub/media/wysiwyg/.htaccess
/pub/media/tmp/*
!/pub/media/tmp/.htaccess
/pub/media/captcha/*
/pub/static/*
!/pub/static/.htaccess

/var/*
!/var/.htaccess
/vendor/*
!/vendor/.htaccess
/generated/*
!/generated/.htaccess
.DS_Store
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/.gitignore